# Does reverse biasing hold any meaning in case if both terminals are n type semiconductors?

Tags: terminology, semiconductor-physics

When we talk about an n-p-n transistor in common emitter configuration, we often say that emitter-collector circuit (the one towards right) is reverse biased. In what sense it is reverse biased?
Here, both terminals are n-type, for such a thing to be reverse biased must not we put positive voltages across both the n-type terminals?

[image]

Comment: I think you are on the wrong site. Try [electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/). You'll get a good answer in no time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a transistor, you need to consider the biasing conditions of both the emitter-base and base-collector junctions.  In forward active operation, the emitter-base is forward biased to inject majority carriers from the emitter into the base.  These transit the base (now as minority carriers with the chance of making it modulated by the base current).  The base-collector junction is then reverse biased to sweep the successful carriers away from the nasty base into the collector where they are, once again, majority carriers. If the base-collector junction is forward biased, the carriers trying to make it from the emitter to the base have no way of doing so - they are pushed away from the collector. So, since the emitter to the base is forward biased, and the base to the collector has to be reverse biased, than overall the emitter to the collector is "reverse biased" to make the individual junctions be biased properly.